# Unmount iscsi volume from bash script

Tags: macos, iscsi, unmount

Plan: I want to unmount  an iscsi volume on my OS X Desktop in a script only if it's mounted. So far, I've identified the disk as `disk4s2` with:

```
diskutil list | grep 'V-Movies' | rev | cut -c1-7 | rev...
```

Continuing the line in order to unmount:

```
diskutil list | grep 'V-Movies' | rev | cut -c1-7 | rev | diskutil unmount [disk4s2]
```

but how do I refer to the disk in square brakets? I realize this may not be the
most efficent solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

xargs is the command you need. It takes stdin and converts it to arguments to pass to a command.

Assuming that `diskutil list | grep 'V-Movies' | rev | cut -c1-7 | rev` gives you the disk name, do:

`diskutil list | grep 'V-Movies' | rev | cut -c1-7 | rev | xargs diskutil unmount`

Comment: The OP said, “only if it’s mounted.”  If there’s a possibility that the disk isn’t mounted when the script is run, you should specify `-r` (or `--no-run-if-empty`) to `xargs` to tell it not to invoke `diskutil unmount` with no arguments if there is no data.

Comment: Good call @Scott :)